# Error uploading image : Call to a member function guessExtension

Tags: php, symfony, image-uploading

I have an entity **Agence** related OneToOne with entity **Photo**

**Agence**

```
class Agence
{
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\DashboardBundle\Entity\Photo", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    */
 private $photo;
```

and this is a brief of entity **Photo**

```
<?php
namespace Project\DashboardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
* Photo
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\DashboardBundle\Entity\PhotoRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Photo
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $url;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
 */
 private $alt;

/**
* @Assert\File(maxSize="1M")
*/
public $file;

  public function setFile($file)
{
$this->file = $file;

if (null !== $this->url) {
  $this->tempFilename = $this->url;

  $this->url = null;
  $this->alt = null;
 }
}

public function getFile()
{
 return $this->file;
}


private $tempFilename;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
 if (null === $this->file) {
  return;
}

$this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();

$this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
}

/**
* @ORM\PostPersist()
* @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
  if (null === $this->file) {
  return;
}

if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
  $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
  if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
    unlink($oldFile);
  }
}

$this->file->move(
  $this->getUploadRootDir(), 
  $this->id.'.'.$this->url  
 );
}

/**
* @ORM\PreRemove()
*/
public function preRemoveUpload()
{
  $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
  if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
  unlink($this->tempFilename);
}
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
  return 'uploads/img';
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
  return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
  return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
}
```

when trying to upload a photo I get this error:

**FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\agence\src\Project\DashboardBundle\Entity\Photo.php line 135**

and the weird thing is that this same code works fine on another entity!!

**SOLVED**
 I forgot to add {{form_enctype (form)}}

Comment: `$this->file` is not null, but something else, not an object. Add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;`  and make `public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)` to see if the setter is called and argument is uploaded file.

Comment: I get this error :
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Project\DashboardBundle\Entity\Photo::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given, called in D:\wamp\www\agence\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 438 and defined in D:\wamp\www\agence\src\Project\DashboardBundle\Entity\Photo.php line 103.
line 103 is: public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)

Comment: impossible, I forgot to add {{form_enctype (form)}}. thank you it works now

Answer (score 1):

you make just 
insert into your form like that
{{form_enctype(form)}}

```
action="{{ path('your_path') }}"  {{form_enctype(form)}}   method="post"
```